# ASP.NET MVC SignalR error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. When I start the application I get the error here:

> SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
>
> No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.

I am not at all using SignalR but I get that error related to SignalR. I am not sure why ...

But when I start my application, it loads browserlink file (please see below) which has references to SignalR. Is this creating problem? Please help.

```
typeof JSON!="undefined"&&(window._vwdJSON=JSON),typeof define!="undefined"&&(window._vwdDefine=define,define=null),typeof window.onbeforeunload!="undefined"&&(window._vwdonbeforeunload=window.onbeforeunload)
;
/* NUGET: BEGIN LICENSE TEXT
 *
 * Microsoft grants you the right to use these script files for the sole
 * purpose of either: (i) interacting through your browser with the Microsoft
 * website or online service, subject to the applicable licensing or use
 * terms; or (ii) using the files as included with a Microsoft product subject
 * to that product's license terms. Microsoft reserves all other rights to the
 * files not expressly granted by Microsoft, whether by implication, estoppel
 * or otherwise. Insofar as a script file is dual licensed under GPL,
 * Microsoft neither took the code under GPL nor distributes it thereunder but
 * under the terms set out in this paragraph. All notices and licenses
 * below are for informational purposes only.
 *
 * NUGET: END LICENSE TEXT */
var JSON;JSON||(JSON={}),(function(){"use strict";function i(n){return n<10?"0"+n:n}function f(n){return o.lastIndex=0,o.test(n)?'"'+n.replace(o,function(n){var t=s[n];return typeof t=="string"?t:"\\u"+("0000"+n.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)})+'"':'"'+n+'"'}function r(i,e){var h,l,c,a,v=n,s,o=e[i];o&&typeof o=="object"&&typeof o.toJSON=="function"&&(o=o.toJSON(i)),typeof t=="function"&&(o=t.call(e,i,o));switch(typeof o){case"string":return f(o);case"number":return isFinite(o)?String(o):"null";case"boolean":case"null":return String(o);case"object":if(!o)return"null";n+=u,s=[];if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(o)==="[object Array]"){for(a=o.length,h=0;h<a;h+=1)s[h]=r(h,o)||"null";return c=s.length===0?"[]":n?"[\n"+n+s.join(",\n"+n)+"\n"+v+"]":"["+s.join(",")+"]",n=v,c}if(t&&typeof t=="object")for(a=t.length,h=0;h<a;h+=1)typeof t[h]=="string"&&(l=t[h],c=r(l,o),c&&s.push(f(l)+(n?": ":":")+c));else for(l in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,l)&&(c=r(l,o),c&&s.push(f(l)+(n?": ":":")+c));return c=s.length===0?"{}":n?"{\n"+n+s.join(",\n"+n)+"\n"+v+"}":"{"+s.join(",")+"}",n=v,c}}typeof Date.prototype.toJSON!="function"&&(Date.prototype.toJSON=function(){return isFinite(this.valueOf())?this.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+i(this.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+i(this.getUTCDate())+"T"+i(this.getUTCHours())+":"+i(this.getUTCMinutes())+":"+i(this.getUTCSeconds())+"Z":null},String.prototype.toJSON=Number.prototype.toJSON=Boolean.prototype.toJSON=function(){return this.valueOf()});var e=/[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,o=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,n,u,s={"\b":"\\b","\t":"\\t","\n":"\\n","\f":"\\f","\r":"\\r",'"':'\\"',"\\":"\\\\"},t;typeof JSON.stringify!="function"&&(JSON.stringify=function(i,f,e){var o;n="",u="";if(typeof e=="number")for(o=0;o<e;o+=1)u+=" ";else typeof e=="string"&&(u=e);t=f;if(f&&typeof f!="function"&&(typeof f!="object"||typeof f.length!="number"))throw new Error("JSON.stringify");return r("",{"":i})}),typeof JSON.parse!="function"&&(JSON.parse=function(n,t){function r(n,i){var f,e,u=n[i];if(u&&typeof u=="object")for(f in u)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(u,f)&&(e=r(u,f),e!==undefined?u[f]=e:delete u[f]);return t.call(n,i,u)}var i;n=String(n),e.lastIndex=0,e.test(n)&&(n=n.replace(e,function(n){return"\\u"+("0000"+n.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)}));if(/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(n.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g,"@").replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g,"]").replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,"")))return i=eval("("+n+")"),typeof t=="function"?r({"":i},""):i;throw new SyntaxError("JSON.parse");})})()
;

 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.0.2; Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation; https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 *
 * NUGET: END LICENSE TEXT */
/*!
 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.0.2
 * http://signalr.net/
 *
 * Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *
 */
```

Comment: Yes, BrowserLink uses SignalR to communicate between your Visual Studio IDE and all the browser you might have open, to synchronize them

Comment: @Can you show the client code? Do should not call a function until connection is established. connection.start().done(function() {....<-- here you can do your stuff --> }

Comment: @reddy Have you tried to disable browserlink?

Comment: @Tester I know nothing about Signalr so I have not done connection.start().done(function())

Comment: @reckface   
I can do that in client side but when I publish my site in server,several Clients will access it.I cannot ask all clients to do this.How can I do this from server side?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using SignalR, but yes, browser link uses SignalR.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link):

> Browser Link is enabled by default. There are several ways to disable
>   it: In the Browser Link dropdown menu, uncheck Enable Browser Link.

[image]

Comment: This works but when I publish my site in server,several Clients will access it.I cannot ask all clients to do this.How can I do this from server side?

Comment: @reddy You don't have to. This is only a debugging feature. It doesn't get "published". It's to allow you to view changes to your site in real-time while debugging.

Comment: I published my site in server and all clients accessing the site are facing the same problem

Comment: @reddy how exactly do you "publish" your site?

Comment: Right click on the project and click on publish.I publish in the IIS by creating virtual directory.

Comment: @reddy when you next publish, ensure you've cleared the output folder. Browser Link or Browser Sync does not copy anything in a publish.

Comment: When ever I publish I do it in a new folder.Doing this in Web.Config might help i think                                                                                 
 <appSettings>
      <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>